# /proc directory stored in a RAM or Hard drive?

Tags: proc

I want to know what is the /proc and what kind of stuffs included in that? And if the /proc store in RAM or Hard drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html):

> /proc is very special in that it is also a virtual filesystem. It's sometimes referred to as a process information pseudo-file system. It doesn't contain 'real' files but runtime system information (e.g. system memory, devices mounted, hardware configuration, etc).

again, from the [same site](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/proc-fs.html):

> The /proc filesystem contains a illusionary filesystem. It does not exist on a disk. Instead, the kernel creates it in memory.

So, to answer your questions:

1. `/proc` contains information about your system and peripherals, it can also be used to *control* kernel behaviour by writing to it. Details about the content of each entry can be found at [the first link](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html).
   For example, you can get your CPU information by inspecting `/proc/cpuinfo`:

   ```
   cat /proc/cpuinfo
   ```

   Or you can change options like IP forwarding:

   ```
   echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward # enables IP forwading
   echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward # disables IP forwading
   ```
2. It's not a *real* filesystem. It is a **representation** of the kernel inner structures. So, it's not *really* stored anywhere, but you can say that its contents are stored in the kernel memory (so "RAM").

Most of the operations you can perform *directly* on the `/proc` filesystem can (and really, **should**) be performed via the `sysctl` utility ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/sysctl.8.html)).

Comment: Technically, I wouldn't say its "contents" are stored anywhere. Some of it is almost certainly generated on-the-fly when the corresponding file is accessed. IIRC some file is indeed a representation of memory as the kernel sees it (and hence can't be stored in memory).

Comment: @Olorin yeah, the second point is not clear. I'm going to elaborate on that soon. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's much clearer. Suggestion: link to Ubuntu http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ or Debian https://manpages.debian.org/ so that it's easier to look up version-specific manpages (e.g, compare  https://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl with https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/procps/sysctl.8.en.html or http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/sysctl.8.html )

Comment: @Olorin fixed manpage link.

Answer (score 1):

To quote [kernel.org documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) :

> The proc  file  system acts as an interface to internal data structures **in the kernel.** It  can  be  used to obtain information about the system and to change
>   certain kernel parameters at runtime (sysctl).

[Kernel itself is loaded in memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257818/85039). Along with `sockfs` and `pipefs`, `procfs` is a [virtual filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system). The directory `/proc` you see on the disk is not permanent - data  in this directory remains there only for the duration of the system running. Once you shut it down, the data does not remain on disk and the directory will be empty. The directory itself merely serves as mountpoint for in-kernel filesystem.

As for information that it contains, the [Wikipedia article on procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) describes it succinctly:

> The proc filesystem (procfs) is a special filesystem in Unix-like operating systems that presents information about processes and other system information in a hierarchical file-like structure, providing a more convenient and standardized method for dynamically accessing process data held in the kernel than traditional tracing methods or direct access to kernel memory.
>
> ...
>
> The proc filesystem provides a method of communication between kernel space and user space. For example, the GNU version of the process reporting utility ps uses the proc file system to obtain its data, without using any specialized system calls.

Among other things, it's a convenient method for processes to know what resources are available to them. For instance, if you run `strace -e open,openat df` you will see that it opens `/proc/self/mountinfo` to obtain information about mountpoints available to it running under your username:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/mountinfo", O_RDONLY) = 3
```