# Where does Ubuntu stores page tables?

Tags: kernel

Per the [kernel Documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt)

> pagemap is a new (as of 2.6.25) set of interfaces in the kernel that allow
> userspace programs to examine the page tables and related information by
> reading files in /proc.

However, when I ran this command when the process 13883 is running on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

```
ll /proc/13883/pagemap
```

I got

```
-r-------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Dec 20 18:05 /proc/13883/pagemap
```

which seems to indicate that Ubuntu stores the info somewhere else, if yes, then where is it?

Another interesting observation is that `/proc/13883/maps` also appears to be size of zero though, there's actually a table in there.

```
...
7ffd62dd7000-7ffd62df8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd62df9000-7ffd62dfc000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd62dfc000-7ffd62dfe000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112177/proc-directory-stored-in-a-ram-or-hard-drive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many "files" in `/proc` are merely a file-like interface to kernel APIs, and don't actually exist on disk. Try `cat` on those files, and the kernel will generate information on the fly and you'll see output. Since the information is generated when needed, these files don't have a meaningful "size".